# Elasticsearch complex multi bucket time aggregation - Session data to User count

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Having dataset with user session data like this:

```
{'username':'TestUser',
 'sessionStartTime' : '2019-02-14 09:00:00'
 'sessionEndTime' : ''2019-02-14 10:20:00'},
{'username':'User2',
 'sessionStartTime' : '2019-02-14 02:00:00'
 'sessionEndTime' : ''2019-02-14 12:00:00'}
```

Is there an easy way to query elastic for an multi-bucket aggregated sum of sessions in a time range?

So basically I want to query for time range 09:00:00 to 11:00:00 and get a aggregated hourly result like this:

```
{'bucketStart' : '2019-02-14 09:00:00',
'bucketEnd' : '2019-02-14 10:00:00',
'sessioncount' : 2},
{'bucketStart' : '2019-02-14 10:00:00',
'bucketEnd' : '2019-02-14 11:00:00',
'sessioncount' : 1}
```

Goal of this is, to use the resulting data to draw a line graph for "online" users sessions count, having only the session data in database.

Comment: Will try to finish on monday, but it should work with a script. "aggs": {
            "timeToConvert": {
              "date_histogram": {
                "interval": "hour",
                "script": "return (doc['sessionEndTime'].value - doc['sessionStartTime'].value);"
              }
            }
          } => we need to loop by hour this substraction inside the script to set the bucket[] array (each element represent a hour) and set the "active" session inside.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I made this on my date (day by day) so adjust the 360000 * 24 (nombre of ms in the date_histogram interval, day for me).

The second thing you could have to do is to cut your date by hour (i mean 14:03 => 14:00, 12:37 => 12h etc..., rounding up for end time and down for start time)

I am not a pro in painless, so I store agg result in a predefined array (size 99), maybe we can do it with a list of something dynamic. Anyway if your session could be longer than 99 hours, adjust it.

The script create a agg by day array, splitting hour by hour the dates.

```
{
    "query": {
         // your filter query
    },
    "aggs": {
    "active_alerts": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "interval": "day",
        "script": {
            "inline": "def currentDate=(doc['sessionStartTime'].value); def endDate=(doc['sessionEndTime'].value); def combined=[99]; def counter = 0; while ((currentDate < endDate) && (counter < 99)) { combined[counter] = currentDate; currentDate += 3600000 * 24 } return combined",
            "lang":"painless"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps, let me know ;)

Comment: Took me a while to test but now the solution works. Thanks for the idea. I modified your solution a little bit. Changed the predefined array to an ArrayList and implemented the counter correctly. To get the whole thing working as kibana date_histogram i had to add `"field":null` and changed `"inline" to "source"` because `inline` is deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

Full solutions for reference :

Additionnaly, allows for open-ended range where the "to" can be absent.

In Kibana, add the following script to the X series Date Histogram agg:

```
{"script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "
def currentDate=(doc['from'].value); 
def endDate=(doc['to']); 
def endDateValue = endDate.size() == 0 ? ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Calendar.getInstance().toInstant(), ZoneOffset.UTC): endDate.value; 
def combined = new ArrayList(); 
while ((currentDate.isBefore(endDateValue))) { combined.add(currentDate); currentDate = currentDate.plusDays(1) } return combined"
        },
        "field": null,
        "calendar_interval": "1d"
}
```

For an ES API agg :

```
GET /<index>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "fromto_range":{
      "date_histogram" : {
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "def currentDate=(doc['from'].value); def endDate=(doc['to']); def endDateValue = endDate.size() == 0 ? ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Calendar.getInstance().toInstant(), ZoneOffset.UTC): endDate.value; def combined = new ArrayList(); while ((currentDate.isBefore(endDateValue))) { combined.add(currentDate); currentDate = currentDate.plusDays(1) } return combined"
          
        },
        "calendar_interval":"1d"
      }
    }
  }
}
```